# How to send API request with "/" and "*" characters in endpoint

Tags: rest, branch, special-characters, github-api, endpoint

im using the github API via Python in order to create branch protection rules for a github repo. Im using the requests library

https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-branch-protection

And one of the rules i have to do need the "/" and the "*" characters in them, for example: "/*test/*" or "test/*" and the API does not work and gives a message not found because it thinks that the "/" and the "*" characters are not part of the branch name, but part of the API endpoint itself.

https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/branches/test/*/protection

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh4F8.png

I have tried to encode the "/" and "*" characters using requests.utils.quote(branch, safe='') but the result is the same either way

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANOY1.png

How can i solve this or get around this issue? Thank you

Comment: I did not have to encode the URL when calling the /protection endpoint for a branch with '/' . I was using the github-cli though. Without looking closely at the source code, it looks like api interprets the branch as is. I assume that this is happening through GraphQL. Make sure to add the required header to your request: `Accept: application/vnd.github+json`.

Comment: Im actually using the requests library through Python. I also don't think the API interprets the branch name to include the "/" character. Hence the issue is am having